# Are the two categories equivalent?

Tags: category-theory, representation-theory

Are the following two categories equivalent?

Let $A$ be an Artin algebra and $I$ be an ideal of $A$.$\newcommand{\mod}{\operatorname{mod}}$
Consider the category $\mathcal{C}=\{M\;|\;MI=0\text{ and }M \in \mod A\}$, where $\mod A$ denotes the finitely generated module category. Denote $B=:A/I$.

Question: How to prove that the two categories 
$\mathcal{C}$ and $\mod B$  are equivalent?  And what is the projective object in $\mathcal{C}$?

Comment: I have edited $\mod A$ to $\operatorname{Mod} A$ mainly because $\mod A$ has different spacing than you would want for this notation. Also your notation fo **C** is a bit unusual - you can use $\mathsf{C}$ `$\mathsf{C}$` in math mode. But I did not change this one - I'll this up to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The natural surjection $A \to B$ gives a restriction of scalars functor $F\colon \mathrm{mod} \ B \to \mathrm{mod} \ A$.  Show that $F$ is fully faithful and then it will be an equivalence between $\mathrm{mod} \ B$ and the image of $F$, which is exactly $C$.  You should note, btw, that these categories are even better than equivalent, they are isomorphic.

Once you know that these categories are equivalent then you know $C$ has enough projectives because $\mathrm{mod} \ B$ does.  For an example of a projective in $C$ just remember that equivalences preserve projectives, so push any projective though $F$ to get a projective for $C$.  For example $B = A/I$ is a projective $B$-module and $F(A/I)$ is just $A/I$ with its natural $A$-action.  So $A/I$ is a projective in $C$.